# How to simplify JavaScript/ECMAScript array literal production?

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, ecmascript-5, javacc

I currently implementing a JavaScript/[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) parser with JavaCC and have problems with the [ArrayLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) production.

```
ArrayLiteral :
    [ Elision_opt ]
    [ ElementList ]
    [ ElementList , Elision_opt ]

ElementList :
    Elision_opt AssignmentExpression
    ElementList , Elision_opt AssignmentExpression

Elision :
    ,
    Elision ,
```

I have three questions, I'll ask them one by one.

---

I have tried to simplify/to rewrite the `ArrayLiteral` production depicted above and finally arrived to the following production (pseudo-grammar):

```
ArrayLiteral:
    "[" ("," | AssignmentExpression ",") * AssignmentExpression ? "]"
```

**My first question: is this rewriting correct?**

Two other quetsions:

- [LOOKAHEADs for the JavaScript/ECMAScript array literal production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908705/lookaheads-for-the-javascript-ecmascript-array-literal-production)
- [How to implement a negative LOOKAHEAD check for a token in JavaCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26909200/how-to-implement-a-negative-lookahead-check-for-a-token-in-in-javacc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that correctly captures the grammar presented.

However, a better rewrite would be:

```
"[" AssignmentExpression ? ( "," AssignmentExpression ? ) * "]"
```

because the rewriting in the OP is not LL(1) -- you cannot distinguish the possibilities without reading the entire `AssignmentExpression` -- whereas with this one you can figure out which alternative to use simply by looking at the first token.

Comment: This is good, I think I will go for it. Although the question with negative `LOOKAHEAD` is still interesting (I need it in a few other places).