# LOOKAHEADs for the JavaScript/ECMAScript array literal production

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, ecmascript-5, javacc

I currently implementing a JavaScript/[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) parser with JavaCC and have problems with the [ArrayLiteral](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) production.

```
ArrayLiteral :
    [ Elision_opt ]
    [ ElementList ]
    [ ElementList , Elision_opt ]

ElementList :
    Elision_opt AssignmentExpression
    ElementList , Elision_opt AssignmentExpression

Elision :
    ,
    Elision ,
```

I have three questions, I'll ask them one by one.

This is the second one.

---

I have simplified this production to the following form:

```
ArrayLiteral:
    "[" ("," | AssignmentExpression ",") * AssignmentExpression ? "]"
```

Please see the first question on whether it is correct or not:

> [How to simplify JavaScript/ECMAScript array literal production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908490/how-to-simplify-javascript-ecmascript-array-literal-production)

Now I have tried to implement it in JavaCC as follows:

```
void ArrayLiteral() :
{
}
{
    "["
    (
        ","
    |   AssignmentExpression()
        ","
    ) *
    (
        AssignmentExpression()
    ) ?
    "]"
}
```

JavaCC complains about ambiguous `,` or `AssignmentExpression` (its contents). Obviously, a `LOOKAHEAD` specification is required. I have spent a lot of time trying to figure the `LOOKAHEAD`s out, tried different things like

- `LOOKAHEAD (AssignmentExpression() ",")` in `(...)*`
- `LOOKAHEAD (AssignmentExpression() "]")` in `(...)?`

and a few other variations, but I could not get rid of the JavaCC warning.

I fail to understand why this does not work:

```
void ArrayLiteral() :
{
}
{
    "["
    (
        LOOKAHEAD ("," | AssignmentExpression() ",")
        ","
    |   AssignmentExpression()
        ","
    ) *
    (
        LOOKAHEAD (AssignmentExpression() "]")
        AssignmentExpression()
    ) ?
    "]"
}
```

Ok, `AssignmentExpression()` per se is ambiguous, but the trailing `","` or `"]"` in `LOOKAHEAD`s should make it clear which of the choices should be taken - or am I mistaken here?

**What would a correct `LOOKAHEAD` specification for this production look like?**

**Update**

This did not work, unfortunately:

```
void ArrayLiteral() :
{
}
{
    "["
    (
        ","
    |
        LOOKAHEAD (AssignmentExpression() ",")
        AssignmentExpression()
        ","
    ) *
    (
        AssignmentExpression()
    ) ?
    "]"
}
```

Warning:

```
Warning: Choice conflict in (...)* construct at line 6, column 5.
         Expansion nested within construct and expansion following construct
         have common prefixes, one of which is: "function"
         Consider using a lookahead of 2 or more for nested expansion.
```

Line 6 is `(` before the first `LOOKAHEAD`. The common prefix `"function"` is simply one of the possible starts of `AssignmentExpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is yet another approach. It has the advantage of identifying which commas indicate an undefined elements without using any semantic actions.

```
void ArrayLiteral() : {} { "[" MoreArrayLiteral() }

void MoreArrayLiteral() : {} {
    "]"
|    "," /* undefined item */ MoreArrayLiteral()
|    AssignmentExpression() ( "]" |  "," MoreArrayLiteral() )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaCC produces top-down parsers. I'll say off the top that I'm not a fan of top-down parser generators, so I'm not a JavaCC expert and I don't have it handy to test.

(**Edit:** I thought something else would work, but I realized afterwards that I don't understand how JavaCC attaches lookahead to actually choices; in the case of `( A | B )* C`, there are actually three possible choices: A, B and C. I thought it would consider all three of them, but it's possible that it does them two at a time. So the following is yet another guess.)

Having said that, I think the following would work, but it involves parsing just about every `AssignmentExpression()` twice.

```
{
    "["
    (
        ","
    |
        AssignmentExpression()
        ","
    ) *
    (
        LOOKAHEAD (AssignmentExpression() "]")
        AssignmentExpression()
    ) ?
    "]"
}
```

As I indicated in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26908490/how-to-simplify-javascript-ecmascript-array-literal-production), a better solution is to rewrite the production differently:

```
"[" AssignmentExpression ? ("," AssignmentExpression ?) * "]"
```

That leads to a one-token lookahead grammar, so you won't need the `LOOKAHEAD` declaration to handle it.

Comment: `ArrayLiteral -> '[' AssignmentExpression ? (',' AssignmentExpression ?) * ']'` - I was thinking about that but it makes my code much more complicated. I actually build `ArrayLiteral ` using a kind-of builder pattern. So on `','` here I won't know whether to add elision or an assignment expression. But is solveable.

Comment: @lexicore: If the optional `AssignmentExpression` is not present, you have an elision. What is the problem? (In other words, you don't decide based on the comma; you decide based on the presence or not of the AssignmentExpression)

Comment: Ah, it's probably nothing. I want to add both assignment expressions as well as elisions to my array. So just looking at `','` in `(...) *` I can't decide whether I have to add an elision here or not, I have to know what was the last step. But this is actually trivial, you're right. I was mislead by my own thoughts.

Comment: I'm not completely clear on the meaning of elisions. However, I think @rici has it right. `"[" {builder.startArrayLiteral();} Item() ("," Item())* "]" {builder.endArrayLiteral();}` and define `Item` by `e=AssignmentExp() {builder.addExp(e);} | {builder.addElision();}`.

Comment: @rici Please see my update and answer - `LOOKAHEAD`s as you posted did not work, unfortunately. But you rewriting worked fine! I just needed another variable to track if the last element was an `AssignmentExpression`.

Comment: @TheodoreNorvell Let's say `[,1,]` produces effectively `[undefined,1]` as well as `[,1]`. I think what you've posted would work.

Comment: @rici Please see the part after the **Update** in the question - I've tried out the code you've posted (with a dosen of variations), I'm getting the posted warning for some reason. I do not understand why, for me it looks perfectly valid. Maybe Theodore could enlighten us...

Comment: @lexicore: OK, I made another stab at it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it (thanks to the answer by `@rici`):

```
JSArrayLiteral ArrayLiteral() : 
{
    boolean lastElementWasAssignmentExpression = false;
}
{
    "["
    (
        (
            AssignmentExpression()
            {
                // Do something with expression
                lastElementWasAssignmentExpression = true;
            }
        ) ?
        (
            ","
            {
                if (!lastElementWasAssignmentExpression)
                {
                    // Do something with elision
                }
            }
            (
                AssignmentExpression()
                {
                    // Do something with expression
                    lastElementWasAssignmentExpression = true;
                }
            ) ?
        ) *
    )
    "]"
    {
        // Do something with results
    }
}
```