# How to implement a negative LOOKAHEAD check for a token in JavaCC?

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, ecmascript-5, javacc

I currently implementing a JavaScript/[ECMAScript 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) parser with JavaCC. I recently [learned](https://javacc.java.net/doc/lookahead.html) about `LOOKAHEAD`s which are handy here as the grammar is not fully LL(1).

One of the things I see in the ECMAScript grammar is "negative lookahead check", like in the following [`ExpressionStatement`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4) production:

```
ExpressionStatement :
    [lookahead ∉ {{, function}] Expression ;
```

So I'll probably need something like `LOOKAHEAD(!("{" | "function"))` but it does not work in this syntax.

**My question is, how could I implement this "negative `LOOKAHEAD`" it in JavaCC?**

After reading the [LOOKAHEAD MiniTutorial](https://javacc.java.net/doc/lookahead.html) I think that an expression like `getToken(1).kind != FUNCTION` may be what I need, but I am not quite sure about it.

Comment: I put my suggested solution to the ArrayLiteral parse at the end of my answer to your second question, so I think this one is irrelevant. But maybe someone will come up with a solution, anyway.

Comment: @rici Yes, I think my immediate problem with `ArrayLiteral` will be resolved, I'll rewrite the question to focus on the negative `LOOKAHEAD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example you provide, I would prefer to use syntactic look ahead, which is in a sense necessarily "positive".

The production for ExpressionStatement is not the place to tackle the problem as there is no choice.

```
void ExpressionStatement() : {} { Expression() ";" }
```

The problem will arise where there is a choice between an expression statement and a block or between an expression statement and a function declaration (or both).

E.g. in Statement you will find

```
void Statement() :{} {
    ...
|
    Block()
|
    ExpressionStatement() 
|   ...
}
```

gives a warning because both choices can start with a "{".  You have two options. One is to ignore the warning. The first choice will be taken and all will be well, as long as Block comes first. The second choice is to suppress the warning with a lookahead specification. like this:

```
void Statement() :{} {
    ...
|
    LOOKAHEAD("{") Block()
|
    ExpressionStatement() 
|   ...
}
```

Syntactic look ahead is, in a sense *positive* -- "take this alternative if X".

If you really want a negative --i.e., "take this alternative if not X"-- look ahead it has to be semantic.

In the case of Statement you could write

```
void Statement() :{} {
    ...
|
    LOOKAHEAD({!(getToken(1)==LBRACE)}) ExpressionStatement() 
|   
    Block()
}
```

I made sure that these are the last two alternatives since otherwise you'd need to include more tokens in the set of tokens that block ExpressionStatement(), e.g. it should not be chosen if the next token is an "if" or a "while" or a "for", etc.

On the whole, you are better off using syntactic lookahead when you can. It is usually more straight forward and harder to mess up.

Comment: I'm actually more interested in "negative `LOOKAHEAD`" than in solving it specificaly for `ExpressionStatement`.

Comment: On the whole, you are better off using syntactic lookahead when you can.  In this case you could use semantic lookahead. E.g. `LOOKAHEAD({getToken(1)!=LBRACE && getToken(1)!=FUNCTION}) ExpressionStatement() | Block()` would work.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question looking for something else, and yes, I am aware that the question was posed nearly 6 years ago.

The most advanced version of JavaCC is [JavaCC21.](https://javacc.com/) and JavaCC21 does allow negative syntactic lookahead.

In JavaCC21 you would write `LOOKAHEAD(~<LBRACE>)` to specify that you only enter the expansion that follows if the next token is *not* an LBRACE, for example. The `~` character negates the lookahead expansion and you can use it to *negate* more complex expansions than a single token, if you want to. For example:

LOOKAHEAD (~(<LBRACE>|<LPAREN>))

There are actually quite a few other features that JavaCC21 that are not present in the legacy JavaCC project. Here is a biggie: the longstanding bug in which nested syntactic lookahead does not work correctly has been fixed. See [here.](https://javacc.com/2020/07/15/nested-syntactic-lookahead-works/)